# Вывести буфер пикселей на экран при помощи OpenGL ES

Tags: c++, c, opengl, android-ndk, opengles

Имеется сгенерированный буфер пикселей. Вывожу их на экран при помощи `ANativeWindow_lock` и `ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost`. Такой метод работает очень медленно. Хочу ускорить вывод графики. Подскажите как при помощи OpenGL ES вывести буфер пикселей на экран. Или может возможно как то ускорить вывод через `ANativeWindow_lock`?

Answer (score 1):

Через OpenGL, самое простое и быстрое - создать текстуру и вывести ее на экран (используя квад и шейдеры, раз уж вопрос про OpenGL ES).